# Why didn't Dumbledore modify the Dursleys' memories so that they wouldn't hurt Harry so much?

Tags: harry-potter, albus-dumbledore

In the books it is mentioned many times that Harry has to live at the Dursleys' because of the protection charm but was all the hardship he went through during his years of living with them necessary as well?
In the HBP, Dumbledore clearly criticizes the Dursleys for how they treated Harry but why didn't he try to modify their memories to really forget about Harry's true identity and maybe love him as a nephew?

Comment: I wavered on this. Don't hesitate to VTRO if you feel my closing this question as a duplicate was incorrect. :)

Comment: @Slytherincess I'm not sure this is a duplicate. Your question is whether Dumbledore did the right choice by sending Harry to the Dursleys. This question is about why didn't Dumbledore just "fix" the Dursleys AFTER sending Harry to them, so that they don't abuse Harry that much.

Comment: @vap78 - As I already mentioned, please don't hesitate to VTRO this question if you think I made the wrong move. As I write this, I do not see any votes to reopen, so, by all means, cast a vote if I'm wrong. :)

Comment: @Slytherincess Vote to reopen requires 3k rep which I don't have. That's why I try to convince you :)

Comment: This does not seem to be a duplicate, as pointed out by @vap78.

Comment: ...Because Dumbledore believes in free will?

Answer (score 5):

Magic can't create love just like that.  Professor Slughorn says so plainly in *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince* chapter 9:

> It is impossible to manufacture or imitate love.

Comment: If they didn't knew Harry was a wizard they would have naturally loved him

Comment: @Arv - They would have noticed the "weird" stuff happening.

Comment: Yes I think you're right Richard. This way they would be scared of the boy even more

Answer (score 0):

If you change a person’s memories, you change a person’s personality. A Harry Potter without those harsh memories of the Dursleys would arguably be a very different one from the one in the stories and possibly not one strong enough to succeed in his future. I understand you wish to change the Dursleys' themselves, but the effect would be the same on Harry as his actual memories would be different. We are all products of our environment, and without overcoming strife there is little encouragement to develop strength.

For further reading on the change of personality due to memory, see any of the studies on Alzheimer's disease. This [college student's work](http://serendip.brynmawr.edu/bb/neuro/neuro05/web3/etrinh.html) is very insightful.

Comment: You mean Dumbledore deliberately put Harry into all that hardship? If so, why was he so angry with them in HBP?